# Why does dd if=/dev/sdb | pigz -c | tee /sdb.img.gz print to console?

Tags: bash, pipe, dd, tee

The command `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb | pigz -c | sudo tee /sdb.img.gz` (omitted `sudo` in the title) prints binary data to console either the output of `dd` or `pigz`. I'm wondering why since all output are caught in a pipe `|` and the last in the chain is redirect to file. So, there's no "leak" to stdout. What am I not getting here?

I'm in `bash` on Ubuntu 20.04 with the shipped versions of the commands.

Comment: -1:  A simple `man tee | head ` would have revealed to you that `tee` _"copies standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output."_  In any case, the point is really at the end of StephenKitts's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tee` *duplicates* its input, sending it (in your case) to its standard output and `/sdb.img.gz`. You can redirect its output to avoid seeing the output on your console:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb | pigz -c | sudo tee /sdb.img.gz > /dev/null
```

I would run `pigz` directly as root instead, avoiding `dd` and `tee`:

```
sudo sh -c 'pigz -c < /dev/sdb > /sdb.img.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

`tee`
prints to the file And stdout, use `cat` or simply redirect stdout if you don't want that

Comment: The point of the `tee` here is to allow elevating privileges using `sudo`; `cat` or redirecting won’t support that.

Comment: @StephenKitt Using sudo, doesn't alter the behaviour of tee,? Adding `>/dev/null` would.

Comment: @StephenKitt sorry, I didn't see the end of your line

Comment: @XTian What Stephen means is that using `sudo cat >/sdb.img.gz` would not work if `/` is not writable by the current user.